# CONCAT multiple fields to a single field, single spaced

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate a `first` `middle` `maiden` and `last` name fields and use that to update a single field which is named `fullname`

For each user any combination of these 4 fields can be filled. From 0 to all 4.
However I also need a single space between each name (not multiple spaces).

```
UPDATE nameTable SET fullname = CONCAT(first, middle, maiden, last);
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

MySQL has `CONCAT_WS` - concatenate with separator

```
CONCAT_WS(' ', first, middle, maiden, last);
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws

As pointed out by `andr` below, make sure any concatenated fields contain `NULL` and not an empty string (`''`) otherwise you will get a double space in the output.

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1fe83/1

#### Further Application

Be careful therefore if in the future you use this function to make a small CSV list, because you won't get the comma for a `NULL` field. You'd have to do a `COALESCE(column, '')` wrapper around each nullable column.

Comment: exactly. I was about to recommend concat_ws() - just make sure empty names have `NULL` value and not `''` (empty string).

Answer (score 6):

empty string solution
`TRIM(BOTH ' ' FROM CONCAT_WS(' ', first, middle, maiden, last))`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim